# On hypercohomology of perverse sheaves

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, perverse-sheaves

I was watching [this Youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=K5aF6WBPLys&ab_channel=InstitutodeCi%C3%AAnciasMatem%C3%A1ticasedeComputa%C3%A7%C3%A3o-ICMC%2FUSP) on a lecture given by J.P. Brasselet on perverse sheaves.

At around 54:37 he mentioned the following result:

Let $X=\cup X_\alpha$ be a Whitney stratified space of dimension $n$. Let $p$ be a perversity function, and let $q=n-2-p_\alpha$ be the complementary perversity. Define $p^{-1}(j)=\min \{\alpha |j\leq p_\alpha\}$. A constructible sheaf complex $S^\bullet$ is perverse if
$$
\dim \{x\in X| H^j(i_x^* S^\bullet)\neq 0\}\leq n- q^{-1} (n-j)\\
\dim \{x\in X| H^j(i_x^! S^\bullet)\neq 0\}\leq n- p^{-1} (n-j)
$$
holds. Then for any perverse sheaf $S^\bullet$, one has
$$
\mathbb{H}^j(X, S^\bullet)=IH^{p, cl}
_{n-i}(X)\\
\mathbb{H}^j_c(X, S^\bullet)=IH^p_{n-i}(X)\\ 
$$

This basically says that, by taking hypercohomology, all perverse sheaves give intersection cohomology. Is this correct ? If true, are there any reference for this result ?

Comment: I'd imagine this is a standard fact for which you can find many resources, but for a detailed proof you can check out proposition 4.9, chapter V section 4, from "Intersection cohomology" by A. Borel

Comment: The correct statement is not that *for all* perverse sheaves $S$, one has $H(X,S)=IH(X)$, it is that *there exists* a perverse sheaf with this property: the intersection complex $IC_X$.